# Wie bezeichnet man einen Kinofilm, der auf einer Fernsehserie basiert?

Tags: single-word-request

There are a variety of German terms for film adaptions of various sources:

> Literaturverfilmung = A work of literature adapted as a film
>   Comicverfilmung = A comic book adapted as a film
>   Videospielverfilumg = A videogame adapted as a film

However, the construct (original medium)+ Verfilmung does not work with Fernsehn:

> [Fernsehverfilmung](http://www.dict.cc/german-english/Fernsehverfilmung.html) = TV version of a cinema film

**How can we label a cinema film that is the result of an adaption of a TV series (for example, Türkisch für Anfänger)?**

One possibility I could think of is "Kinoadaption"; however, Kinoadaption does not reveal the original medium upon which the adaption is based, and it seems to be used primarily in reference to original materials (i.e. "Originalcomic zur Kinoadaption").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could take `Filmadaption` or `Spielfilmadaption`.

There are some examples of this usage:

> Türkisch für Anfänger ist eine deutsche **Spielfilmadaption** der gleichnamigen ARD-Serie aus dem Jahr 2012.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BCrkisch_f%C3%BCr_Anf%C3%A4nger_(Film))

> Derzeit befinden sich einige **Filmprojekte mit Serienbezug** in Entwicklung,
>
> „The Walking Dead“: Wie wäre es mit einer **Filmadaption**?

Source: [Serienjunkies: Von der Serie zum Film: Traum- und Alptraum-Projekte](http://www.serienjunkies.de/news/serie-film-traum-alptraum-projekte-42344.html)

But be aware, if a book can also have a `Filmadaption`. (see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaption_(Literatur)#Filmadaptionen))

Another possibility: **Serienverfilmung** or **Serienadaption**

Examples:

> Die bekanntesten Serienverfilmungen
>
> Im Anschluss findet ihr eine Liste der bekanntesten Serienverfilmungen.
>
> [...]Türkisch für Anfänger[...]
>
> Akte X – Die unheimlichen Fälle des FBI[...] Der Erfolg der zweiten **Serienadaption** hielt sich jedoch in Grenzen[...]

Source: [Maxdome](http://blog.maxdome.de/kino-film/von-der-serie-zum-film-die-bekanntesten-serienfilme)

Depending of the type you could use `Filmfortsetzung` (the story is continued in he film):

> Wir stellen eine Liste von Serien zusammen, die im Film fortgesetzt wurden.
>
> Nach dem offenen Ende der Echtzeitserie „24“ soll nun sehr bald schon eine **Filmfortsetzung** produziert werden

Source: [Filmjunkies Die besten Filmfortsetzungen zu TV-Serien](http://www.filmjunkies.de/news/besten-filmfortsetzungen-serien-37007.html)

Answer (score 3):

The term

> Film zur Serie

is also used for this purpose, perhaps because there is no common single word.